# What is the green dot on the snippet icon in Chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome, code-snippets, devtools

Sometimes when I create a new snippet in Chrome devtools its icon has a green dot at the lower right. Sometimes the same thing happens when I edit a snippet. I haven't used snippets in a few months, and I remember there was something I did that made the dot go away, but I can't remember what it was.

What is the significance of the dot? What am I supposed to do when I see one? I looked at lot of web pages describing the use of snippets and even a few videos, and I found no mention of this dot in any of them. Furthermore, the new snippets the videos showed being created did not get a green dot on their icon.

Comment: Status code 'OK'? Not sure what you're referencing got pictures?

Comment: I noticed that when hovering my mouse cursor over a snippet icon that has a green dot the tooltip says "Linked to snippet:///..." rather than just "snippet:///..." like when hovering over a snippet icon that doesn't have the green dot. I'm not sure what that means yet, but might be a clue.

Comment: This thread (https://groups.google.com/g/google-chrome-developer-tools/c/8NSf-2AKNmM) makes it sound like when a JS file is "linked" in devtools it means that when you save your edits it saves to the linked file on disk. What this means in the context of snippets I'm still trying to understand. I did notice that as soon as I run a new snippet then the dot appears. Then if I remove all the text in a snippet and run it the dot goes away.

Answer (score 0):

The green dot means that file is linked to the source file within a workspace. It allows you to edit the file in the Dev Tools editor and the source file will be updated with those changes.
[Chrome dev tools. Edit and save with Workspaces](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/)